# Go concurrent slice access

Tags: concurrency, go

I'm doing some stream processing in Go and got stuck trying to figure out how to do this the "Go way" without locks.

This contrived example shows the problem I'm facing.

- We get one `thing` at a time.
- There is a goroutine which buffers them into a slice called `things`.
- When `things` becomes full `len(things) == 100` then it is processed somehow and reset
- There are `n` number of concurrent goroutines that need to access `things` before it's full
- Access to the "incomplete" `things` from other goroutines is not predictable.
- Neither `doSomethingWithPartial` nor `doSomethingWithComplete` needs to mutate `things`

Code:

```
var m sync.Mutex
var count int64
things := make([]int64, 0, 100)

// slices of data are constantly being generated and used
go func() {
  for {
    m.Lock()
    if len(things) == 100 {
      // doSomethingWithComplete does not modify things
      doSomethingWithComplete(things)
      things = make([]int64, 0, 100)
    }
    things = append(things, count)
    m.Unlock()
    count++
  }
}()

// doSomethingWithPartial needs to access the things before they're ready
for {
  m.Lock()
  // doSomethingWithPartial does not modify things
  doSomethingWithPartial(things)
  m.Unlock()
}
```

1. <s>I know that slices are immutable so does that mean I can remove the mutex and expect it to still work (I assume no)</s>.
2. How can I refactor this to use channels instead of a mutex.

**Edit:** Here's the solution I came up with that does not use a mutex

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func Incrementor() chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        count := 0
        for {
            ch <- count
            count++
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

type Foo struct {
    things   []int
    requests chan chan []int
    stream   chan int
    C        chan []int
}

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    foo := &Foo{
        things:   make([]int, 0, 100),
        requests: make(chan chan []int),
        stream:   Incrementor(),
        C:        make(chan []int),
    }
    go foo.Launch()
    return foo
}

func (f *Foo) Launch() {
    for {
        select {
        case ch := <-f.requests:
            ch <- f.things
        case thing := <-f.stream:
            if len(f.things) == 100 {
                f.C <- f.things
                f.things = make([]int, 0, 100)
            }
            f.things = append(f.things, thing)
        }
    }
}

func (f *Foo) Things() []int {
    ch := make(chan []int)
    f.requests <- ch
    return <-ch
}

func main() {

    foo := NewFoo()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(i) * 100)
            things := foo.Things()
            fmt.Println("got things:", len(things))
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        for _ = range foo.C {
            // do something with things
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: slices are not immutable. Strings are.

Comment: Slices are mutable. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @FUZxxl the array a slice points to is mutable, but the slice itself is not. (AFAIK)

Comment: @peterSO how would you go about mutating a slice? Any operations on a slice result in a new slice.

Comment: @ilia choly This is somewhat true. Notice that I can do *(&someslice) = someslice[a:b] to overwrite the memory location someslice lies in. Also, if you have a global variable that is a slice, you can of course assign to it and change the slice the global variable contains.

Comment: @iliacholy `myslice[5] = new_value`?

Comment: [String types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types): "Strings behave like slices of bytes but are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the contents of a string." For a string: `str := "    "; str[0] = 'x' // cannot assign to str[0]`. For a slice: `slc := make([]byte, 4); slc[0] = 42 // can assign to slc[0]`.

Comment: I'm not understanding the benefit of the goroutine here. If both the main thread and the goroutine are primarily operating on the same slice, but it needs to be locked during its operation, you wouldn't seem to gain anything by the separate routine... except for the tiny `count++` operation. Seems like an inherently synchronous problem.

Comment: @cthom06 you're mutating the array the slice points to, not the slice itself.

Comment: @FUZxxl ah ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: @amnotiam this is a contrived example. In my actual code the goroutines are requests from clients. See the 5th bullet point in my question.

Comment: @ilia choly You could try to use channels for synchronization. The select statement might become handy here.

Comment: @iliacholy That's equivalent to saying "all pointers in C are immutable, you can only change the memory they point to." While technically true, it's a pointless definition, because in that case _everything_ in Go is immutable.

Comment: @cthom06 hmm, I guess you're right.

Comment: @FUZxxl I've updated my answer with a channel based solution. Can I get some input?

Comment: Don't realloc, just reslice. So convert `f.things = make([]int, 0, 100)` into `f.things = f.things[:0]`

Comment: @Volker can't do that, then I'll be changing the values in the array I've already handed out.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that the "Go way" is probably just to use a mutex for this. It's fun to work out how to do it with a channel but a mutex is probably simpler and easier to reason about for this particular problem.